# Wordpress Mixed Content Error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have 3 sites in a Multisite environment . I also have SSL enabled for the admin section . But I get lots of "**Mixed Content**" errors on the admin only for **ONE** site . As a result many scripts and style sheets in the admin are broken .

If there was some problem with my **htaccess rules** or the **wp_config** file, then there should have been the same problem on the other sites too . But the other 2 sites work properly .

I have almost same plugins installed on all three sites . I tried deactivating the plugins . Also tried vainly using the basic **Wordpress 2015** theme. So I have **excluded** **Plugins and Theme** as causes for this problem .

Can anyone please suggest as to why this can be happening ?

```html
 Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-includes/js/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/capsman/framework/styles/admin.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/capsman/admin.css?ver=1.3.2"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/capsman/framework/styles/admin.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/capsman/admin.css?ver=1.3.2"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/sections/boxes/icon.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/sections/features/icon.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/sections/banners/icon.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/custom-status/lib/custom-status.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/edit-page.min.css?ver=2.1.1"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/editorial-metadata/lib/editorial-metadata.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/css/edit-flow-admin.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/captcha/css/style.css?ver=4.2.2"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/ig-analytics//assets/css/admin.css?ver=1.3"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/css/jquery.ui.theme.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/css/jquery.listfilterizer.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/notifications/lib/notifications.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/user-groups/lib/user-groups.css?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/500201259536538-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/Econsultancy-Mobile-Survey-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/ThinkstockPhotos-482221483-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/seo-localization-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/ID-10091333-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/South-Korea-Flag-On-Hand-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/search-everything/static/css/admin.css?ver=8.1.3"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/search-everything/static/css/se-compose.css?ver=8.1.3"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/ig-analytics//assets/js/admin.js?ver=1.3"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/search-everything/static/js/searcheverything.js?ver=8.1.3"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/admin/css/admin.css?ver=2.4.6"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Australian-Landscape-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Australian-Flag-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Digital-Content-Strategy-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/dms15_singapore_sydney_banner_900x600px-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Digital-Directionsl-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/04/2015_gartner_mq_mccm_1600x900-1200x675-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/mobile-marketing-asia-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/04/mobile-video-marketing-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/03/2400x800-Landing-pg-Banner2-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/04/dms15_singapre_sydney_banner_3400x2267-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/04/Nissan-Motor-Corporation_Final-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/bwp-google-xml-sitemaps/images/icon_menu.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/captcha/images/px.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/settings/lib/eflogo_s32.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/search-everything/static/js/searcheverything.js?ver=8.1.3"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/custom-status/lib/custom-status.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/js/wp-seo-admin-global.min.js?ver=2.1.1"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/ef_date.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/calendar/lib/calendar.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/jquery.listfilterizer.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/jquery.quicksearch.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/notifications/lib/notifications.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/user-groups/lib/user-groups.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/admin/css/admin.css?ver=2.4.6"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/sections/boxes/icon.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/sections/features/icon.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/sections/banners/icon.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/500201259536538-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/Econsultancy-Mobile-Survey-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/ThinkstockPhotos-482221483-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/06/seo-localization-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/ID-10091333-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/South-Korea-Flag-On-Hand-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Australian-Landscape-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Australian-Flag-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Digital-Content-Strategy-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/dms15_singapore_sydney_banner_900x600px-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/Digital-Directionsl-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/dms15_singapore_sydney_banner_900x600px-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/04/2015_gartner_mq_mccm_1600x900-1200x675-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/files/2015/05/mobile-marketing-asia-100x100.jpg"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/captcha/images/px.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/settings/lib/eflogo_s32.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed display content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/bwp-google-xml-sitemaps/images/icon_menu.png"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/js/wp-seo-admin-global.min.js?ver=2.1.1"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/ef_date.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/calendar/lib/calendar.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/custom-status/lib/custom-status.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/jquery.listfilterizer.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/jquery.quicksearch.js?ver=0.8"
 
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/notifications/lib/notifications.js?ver=0.8"
```

Comment: Can you please share to which content do the mixed content errors relate?

Comment: Yes, I get those errors for scripts , stylesheets , as well as images .

Comment: Wordpress admin -> settings -> general -> wordpress address & website address, do they contain `https://` ? **BTW** Is it a multisite?

Comment: No they do not contain https . Reason is that I need ssl enabled only for admin section . Front end loads with http . Yes , all three sites are in a multisite environment

Comment: You need https only for the admin? That would be complicated then. You need to tell WP that you're using `ssl` so it would use `https://` when it's calling to the resources (styles, js, images).

Comment: Yes, like I said I enabled https on the admin by setting define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true)
Also , I have already purchased a certificate . 
On the other two sites , there are no issues , there are issues only for this site .

Comment: I'm afraid that based only on what you've mentioned in your question it would be hard for me to locate the problem. Maybe you have a specific configuration at that site that overwrite that force_ssl_admin setting? (Also, maybe this is relevant: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/force_ssl_admin)

Comment: I have the same configuration on all three sites.  Only difference is a few plugins. Despite of deactivating those plugins , the error persists .
Also , even I cannot find the root of this issue . Have been days I'm researching this.

Comment: Do you think that there maybe some problem with the SSL certificate issued for this particular site ? Can that be a cause of the error ?

Comment: Can you please share the full list of mixed content resources? If you're using Chrome or FF, in case that the SSL cert is invalid, you'll see a red "x" icon on the lock icon that's on the address bar.

Comment: Following are a few errors that I am getting

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/themes/pagelines/admin/css/admin.css?ver=2.4.6"

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/common/js/ef_date.js?ver=0.8"

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://sitename/wp-content/plugins/edit-flow/modules/calendar/lib/calendar.js?ver=0.8"


Also , I do not see a red cross in the address bar

Comment: I am not able to attach images since I do not have the required reputation to do so .

Comment: While I need the exact mixed content files (not just `admin/css/`, rather `admin/css/blabla.css`, it seems that the problematic files aren't the system's files rather the theme's and plugin's files.

Comment: Yes , most of the errors belong to theme and plugin files . However ,there are a few system files too . I have attached the errors in the original question .

Comment: Good. The problem is that those plugins and theme aren't compatible to the ADMIN SSL setting (not proper wp coding standards) . If you know php and html - you need to update the URLs of those files, otherwise - ask  for the plugin's author's help / disable them.

Comment: But , like I mentioned before , we are using the same plugins and theme for the other sites in this multisite installation . I do not get those errors for other sites at all . Only for this one site , the console shows the errors .

Comment: Offir Baruch , the issue was a few redirect rules in my .htaccess file . I appreciate your help . Thank you so much !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add the following to wp-config.php:

```
 $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. i tried everything. but this answer is best i fount on internet

Comment: now when I try to access wp administration it says `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

Comment: This error message usually occurs when there is an issue with the user's role or capabilities in WordPress. It can be caused by a number of things, such as a problem with the user's account or a conflict with a plugin or theme that is modifying the user's roles and capabilities.

Comment: Absolutely the rightest answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will guide you step by step how you can easily solve this error:

Step#1: First you need to identify where that mixed content is, to identify mixed content please open your website in google chrome and right click on your website web page and select Inspect element, when inspect element open please click console and see where is mixed content see the below image
[image]

Step#2: You notice in above image mixed content issue happen when we are loading some data from insecure website, so host all images and data on your website..

this way i resolve mixed content issues in my website i hope it work of your..

Comment: Thank you for your reply . But all the scripts and stylesheets that appear in the console are already hosted on my server itself.

Comment: can you please send me specific error so i try to solve your issue... thanks

Comment: I get the same errors as you provided in the screenshots above . Nothing else.

Comment: so all error because your website using some files from insecure website please do a investigation of you website source code your will find some insecure files in your website code i am sure...

Comment: Hello , the issue was a few rules in my .htaccess file . Appreciate your help . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Since these answers didn't solve my problem, hopefully mine will help someone:

---

Just add:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
```

to `\opt\bitnami\apache\conf\httpd.conf`, right below "User daemon" and "Group daemon", around line 177, outside of any `<IfModule>` tag.

My setup is a normal WordPress app running on `AWS Lightsail` with SSL enabled through `Apache`.

This will automatically make all HTTP based requests into HTTPS. For more info, please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests).